# What kind of animals can be raised like cows?

Tags: domestication, livestock

Looking for animals specifically used for meat.  They must be able to be kept in way that that cows can be,  That could mean in a pen with corn or in a pasture with just a tall fence.

Edit: I know the question is simple but even deer could feasibly be raised in some way like this, albeit less efficiently. I also left out I would want them to survive in the wild because they are from there (as in not currently domesticated or at least feral).

Comment: With respect to deer, deer are too skiddish and bucks are too aggressive to reasonably domesticate.

Comment: @Echo61505 does your requirement for them to be able to survive 'feral' include being able to recover them for farming? Birds can be clipped to prevent the farmed generations from flying away, that won't stop future generations if they are left to go feral though, assuming they have the food available to survive that generation. As to your comment re: Rodents and such-like are feasible, just not economic when cattle and sheep are easier to manage & process. Just securing the farm against escape would cost substantial initial capital and a 'tall fence' just won't do. Deer are farmed.

Comment: Wikipedia has a long [list of domesticated and semi-domesticated animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_domesticated_animals)...

Comment: If you know that this question is "simple", why do you need to ask? This is a serious question that you should perhaps answer. Maybe you've heared if other farm animals and maybe want to truly know something different

Comment: Try Yaks, If climate is no issue, Yaks are usually domesticated, can survive in the wild, but are suitable for high altitudes and cold climates.

Comment: @Beefster: Deer are too skittish?  Tell that to Santa!  Or to the Sami people of northern Scandanavia, who've been using domesticated reindeer for centuries.  And closer to home (at least if you're American) deer farming is a real thing: https://modernfarmer.com/2014/02/deer-farming-next-adventure-agriculture/

Comment: @Beefster or if you are in Britain. http://www.bdfpa.org

Comment: V.Aggarwal I don't have a climate but the area it should be in is from the Equator to 40 degrees latitude north and
0 to 90 degrees east.

Comment: The only correct answer is "veal"! I know I'm going to hell for that but I pity whoever has to drag me down there.

Comment: Do they need to be domesticated in antiquity or using modern technology? What criteria is used to decide what animal is best? Without this information the question is too broad.

Comment: This question is way too broad. With nearly 9 million species of animals out there, it'd be more prudent to ask "Can X animal be raised like a cow?" Just a friendly reminder, but Stack Exchange is not an idea aggregation website. There is no best answer here without someone going through all the animals and listing every last one that could be a valid candidate.

Comment: Tamashii I don't think thats true if nothing else most of that life is sea life or if you want to go by taxa theyre worms. I would remind that it is intended to be used for it's meat which limits the possibilities further. Raptors and Arachnids such as spiders would be poor answers as well

Comment: From what Beefster said song birds and ladybugs would be poor answers in comparison to Chickens, Crickets, and Grasshoppers which I bet have more than one species. So authors have the ability to use words that can be used for multiple species and can discern between a good and bad answer to give.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Just about any docile grazing animal will do.

Everything we have domesticated at this point was indigenous before we started domesticating it, so that constraint of "needs to survive in the wild" doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If you mean something that could survive if its farmer died... Maybe someone could help narrow my list down.

### Yaks and Water Buffalo

Both were raised in antiquity and mirror cows pretty closely in functionality.

<sub>*Thanks to John for this one*</sub>

### Sheep

Sheep have been used as a food source in many cultures historically. As a nice bonus, you also get wool

### Llamas and Alpacas

Llamas are the feistier of the two and both were used more for their "wool" and packing ability, but they could conceivably be used as food sources.

### Horses, Donkeys, and Oxen

There's no biological law preventing the consumption of horses, donkeys, and oxen. It's just we found they were more useful as beasts of burden because of their strength and stamina.

### Camels

Exotic, But should work just fine. Probably better for packing through desert climates, but is certainly a viable food source.

### Tapirs (maybe)

These haven't been used historically, but are chill enough to domesticate for meat. The major issue is that their reproductive rate is quite low- about one offspring per two years. Secondary to that is that tapirs are nocturnal and compete for the same food sources as humans. They're more likely to simply be hunted than domesticated, though pet tapirs are not unheard of.

## Some non-grazing animals could work as well

### Rabbits

Rabbits have been eaten and farmed by many societies throughout history and can even be found in supermarkets today.

They're a little tricky since they're smaller, have more predators, and burrow, but are a viable food source because of their high reproductive rates. Since they're so small, you can have rabbit meat fresh and don't really have to worry about preservation.

<sub>*Thanks to jamesqf for making a case for including rabbits*</sub>

### Guinea Pigs and Capybara

Basically the same deal as with rabbits, but indigeneous to South America.

<sub>*Thanks, Ynneadwraith*</sub>

### Goats and Pigs

Goats and pigs don't actually graze; they browse. This effectively means you have to actively feed them. I suppose you could also use forest land as well, but that has its own set of problems.

The nice thing about goats is that they eat just about everything, so leftovers and scraps can go to the goats. You also get milk, so they can more functionally mirror cows.

Pigs are not as efficient as you might think and pork is hard to preserve without refrigeration. They're also quite a bit pickier than goats, so you may end up with more waste from their slop feed.

### Chicken, Turkeys, Ducks, and Geese

You have to do something about their flying, so you either need to have a lot of land, put them in cages, or clip their wings. Turkeys are the least problematic of the four.

You also get eggs. That's a nice bonus.

<sub>*Thanks to jamesqf for making a case for including fowl*</sub>

### Snakes (maybe)

Since snakes are ectothermic (cold-blooded), their being carnivorous isn't as much of a problem because you don't have to feed them nearly as often. They have pretty large litters as well. I'm unsure about growth logistics and meat efficiency.

The biggest problem is that containment is very difficult (much harder than with rabbits). Fences aren't going to work and walls might still fail to contain them.

<sub>*Thanks to John for the point on containing snakes*</sub>

Comment: What about smaller animals such as mice or birds?

Comment: @Echo61505 You must have heared of chicken and people having mice as pets ...

Comment: @Echo61505: smaller animals give you less meat, require more food per mass, tend to have more predators, and require finer fence enclosures. I thought about including rabbits since they reproduce like crazy, but then I realized that burrowing would be a problem. That, and you'd have to do something about foxes. Birds require a ceiling to enclose and have an even higher food-to-mass ratio. Chickens and turkeys are the only viable sources I can think of and only because they aren't great at flying.

Comment: @Beefster: Rabbits are quite commonly raised for meat. No one seems to have thought about pigs, and how about kangaroos?.  Among birds, ducks and geese are also raised for eggs & meat, also (but less commonly) guinea hens, peafowl, quail, pheasants...  And of course ostriches & emus ("The Next Red Meat")

Comment: fences are not good at containing snakes. Even walls are only sometimes successful.

Comment: Beefster rabbits were farmed in Medieval Europe, and pure highly prized. In England structures such as this semi-fortified lodge were were Warreners protected their rabbits.https://www.english-heritage.org.uk/visit/places/thetford-warren-lodge/history/rabbits-warreners/

Comment: @Sarriesfan: Not just medieval Europe.  Rabbit was common in European supermarkets when I lived there.  In the US, it's also available on Amazon, other on-line sources, and a number of supermarkets.

Comment: @jamesqf we used to shoot our rabbit when I was a boy and local butchers sell them in the game season quite often. But my point to Beefster was that rabbits where so prized that fairly impressive structures were built to help protect them.

Comment: Rabbits are farmed by allowing them to be semi-wild then ferreting them out when you want some. Runner ducks are called runner ducks for a reason, they're the most popular farmed variety.

Comment: Guinea Pigs are farmed in South America too. Kept in the home, running about the walls and caught when required. Capybara might also be a viable option.

Comment: You forgot Yaks and Water Buffalo both being domesticated in antiquity. Both of which are closer to cattle in use and behavior than anything else on the list.

Comment: I'm skeptical about tapirs.  Generally speaking, if an animal hasn't been domesticated it's because doing so is not cost effective or practical. Could you provide sources?

Comment: @ArcanistLupus a quick google search suggests that they have been kept as pets in some cases.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus While that does hold as a general rule, it's probably not fine-grained enough to be ruling things out with on its own. The lack of cost-effectiveness could be as little as 'we already had x', which is not an assessment of y's domesticability, only that it didn't get there first.

Comment: @Beefster mountain lions have been kept as pets too, and they have terrible domestication potential. Don't confuse the taming of individuals with the domestication of the species - the two are very different.

Comment: @Ynneadwraith I agree, which is why I asked for sources rather than denying the possibility. I'm not sure I find "we already had X" to be a convincing explanation though, considering both sheep and goats were domesticated.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the aptly named Beefster's excellent list, add:

### Reindeer

> Although there is little doubt that the domestication of mammals was
>   instrumental for the modernization of human societies, even basic
>   features of the path towards domestication remain largely unresolved
>   for many species. Reindeer are considered to be in the early phase of
>   domestication with wild and domestic herds still coexisting widely
>   across Eurasia. This provides a unique model system for understanding
>   how the early domestication process may have taken place. We analysed
>   mitochondrial sequences and nuclear microsatellites in domestic and
>   wild herds throughout Eurasia to address the origin of reindeer
>   herding and domestication history. Our data demonstrate independent
>   origins of domestic reindeer in Russia and Fennoscandia. This implies
>   that the Saami people of Fennoscandia domesticated their own reindeer
>   independently of the indigenous cultures in western Russia. We also
>   found that augmentation of local reindeer herds by crossing with wild
>   animals has been common. However, some wild reindeer populations have
>   not contributed to the domestic gene pool, suggesting variation in
>   domestication potential among populations. These differences may
>   explain why geographically isolated indigenous groups have been able
>   to make the technological shift from mobile hunting to large-scale
>   reindeer pastoralism independently. ([ref](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rspb.2008.0332))

[image: Reindeer milking.jpg]
Public Domain, [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=654990)

Answer (score 0):

Given temperament and feeding habits, the best animals for domestication have always been herd animals that are herbivores.

They're genetically well disposed towards being kept in groups, and are less likely to see their handlers as a snack than are carnivores.

Of course there are risks with herbivores as well, which will need to be bred out over generations.
Wild boar for example are rather aggressive and are as likely to try to kill you than run from you if you encounter them in a forest (especially if they have young). But the fact that we now have domesticated pigs shows it can be done.

Some animals seemingly can never be domesticated. Hippos may be one example (though it may just be nobody's ever tried hard enough, thinking it's not worth the effort to tame those ill tempered behemoths).

Ideally you'd want something that can be kept contained with a relatively easy to build enclosure (another reason why hippos haven't been attempted no doubt, they're rather larger and stronger than pigs and wild cows). So a smallish to medium sized animal, not too much larger than a human, with a gentle temperament, but not too skittish, would be ideal.

Enter the cow, the llama, the pony/horse, some pig species, rabbits, things like that.

I'm keeping this deliberately vague as I don't know your exact setting which may well be on a fantasy world with different species, but the characteristics you select for will be the same.

Carnivorous pack animals could be included that meet roughly the same criteria, but you're going to have more trouble getting them to be docile enough and not turn on their handlers. Think wolves, foxes, mink, ferrets, cats (and yes, all those will at times turn on their handlers if you're not careful, as everyone who owns a cat will know from the scars. Cats can scratch and bite, even when kept as pets though it's often more out of reflex during excited play or when scared than deliberate).